# Version resolving failed, Shared Preferences with Audio Recorder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Trying to add `audio_recorder` as a dependency with `shared_preferences` gives version resolving failed.

```
Because shared_preferences_windows 2.0.0 depends on file ^6.0.0 and no versions of shared_preferences_windows match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0 requires file ^6.0.0.
And because audio_recorder >=0.0.6 depends on file ^5.0.4, audio_recorder >=0.0.6 is incompatible with shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0.
And because shared_preferences 2.0.5 depends on shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0 and no versions of shared_preferences match >2.0.5 <3.0.0, audio_recorder >=0.0.6 is incompatible with shared_preferences ^2.0.5.
So, because my_app depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.5 and audio_recorder ^1.0.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because my_app depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.5 and audio_recorder ^1.0.2, version solving failed.)
```

Tried using `flutter_audio_recorder` package instead but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `pub` find which version works by not specifiying the version of `audio_recorder` plugin in `pubspec.yaml`, like this:

```
audio_recorder:
```

Now run `flutter pub get` and then, optionally you can look in the `pubspec.lock` and see what version you got so you can put it in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: This worked. Although I had to not specify version for both `shared_preferences` and `audio_recorder`

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

it isn't the best solution but maybe it is helpful.

add **dependency_overrides** to pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  file ^6.0.0
```